# Can I delete /Library/Updates on EI Capitan

Tags: software-update, disk-space

I'm trying reduce my drive space requirement. I discovered `/Library/Updates` is taking up a lot of space.

After a quick Google, I found `/Library/Updates` is used to store system updates file which have not been applied.

So is it safe to clean up `/Library/Updates`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Theoretically, there should only be updates in that folder until you actually run the updates, then they should be cleared - so my first suggestion would be to check the App Store app & run any pending updates from there, reboot, then recheck the folder.

Anything left over at that point ought to be safe to delete, though I would retain the `index.plist` `PPDVersions.plist` & `ProductMetadata.plist` files, if present, unless you are having general updating issues, as I suspect they are designed to accurately track the update state.

Comment: After running the updates, will the net amount of available storage be around the same as it was before the update?