# Stop latest upgrade from installing

Tags: macos, auto-update

I  downloaded by accident the latest update by Apple, currently running 10.13.1.

I can't upgrade to 10.13.2 due to a problem with the GPU which makes it impossible to boot up.

Right now it's asking to restart in order to install it. Is there a way to stop the installer from running ?

```
I found the solution here
```

[Can I delete /Library/Updates on EI Capitan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211952/can-i-delete-library-updates-on-ei-capitan)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to [force quit](https://support.apple.com/HT201276) the installer. To do this, press the <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd> keys to bring up the Force Quit Applications window. Then select the installer and click on the Force Quit button.

Another option is to make sure the installer is the active app and then hold down the <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd> keys for at least three seconds to immediately force quit it.

Comment: Thank you Monomeeth, because I had already downloaded it, what I had to do was go to /Library/Updates and delete modify the two xml files so that it won't update on reboot.