# Where can I find the downloaded Catalina files to free up the disk space?

Tags: macos, mojave, software-update, catalina

I am running macOS Mojave. I've downloaded Catalina, but I regret to install it. The download was completed. Where can I find the downloaded file(s) to free up the disk space?

- I haves checked in Applications folder.
- I checked with `find`, couldn't find the files.

Comment: Regular release OS full installers are in Applications, named "Install [macOS name]", so I'd check there first, but I don't really know if that applies to betas.

Comment: It's not there, checked before asking this question. Thanks though.

Comment: Did you allow the download to complete? They tend to be buried way down inside private/var before they're complete.

Comment: yup, the download is complete

Comment: Then I'd suggest getting hold of [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) (freeware) Search 'files & folders', 'all words', 'Invisible...' with the term 'catalina', or failing that 'only folders' &  'com.apple.appstore'  & check inside each folder that is found. [It's a slow search because it's not indexed, but it will find anything you specify, if it exists]

Comment: Thanks, tried with `find` utility already, will EasyFind change anything?

Comment: idk how `find` works, so I don't know. I do know indexed search, ie Spotlight, will never find it.

Comment: @Tetsujin I found your answer. on [Can I delete /Library/Updates on EI Capitan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211952/can-i-delete-library-updates-on-ei-capitan) Also, CL tools update are pending on my Mac and they are stored in the mentioned folder. I don't know about Catalina. Found this question too. [Mac App Store update stuck (Installing - Calculating…)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/82551)

Comment: I’m voting to close this against the great questions we have on finding any file. The system cleans up temporary downloads after a restart or the system just needs to purge snapshots from files recently deleted. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341898/135gb-of-hidden-space-snapshot-metadata-tree-invalid-error-in-disk-first-aid This is likely not just an installer, but an edit to the question might clear up if this isn’t a duplicate. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337450/is-there-a-script-i-can-use-to-download-the-mojave-installer-without-being-signe

Comment: Daisy Disk is the program I use to attack this and all other sorts of storage issues. you can muddle with `find` and `du` and System Information - find large files to get rid of non-temporary files, but for system files, nothing beats the tool designed for the job - Daisy Disk. Try the free evaluation if you’re not convinced it is worth your time.